# SQLAlchemy: relationship collection lazy loading

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

As per the SQLAlchemy [documentation on relationship loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html):

> When the given collection or reference is first accessed on a particular object, an additional SELECT statement is emitted such that the requested collection is loaded.

How do I achieve loading behavior such that only the single elements of a relationship collection that I access are loaded, rather than the entire collection all at once?

I have heard of [deferred column loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_columns.html?highlight=deferred%20loading#deferred-column-loading); this would be more like "deferred row loading". Rather than deferring loading of attributes, I'd like to defer loading of relationship collection elements.

Desired use case:

```
# Persist instance.
coln = Collection([1, 2, 3])
session.add(coln)
session.commit()

# Test lazy loading.
print('data' in coln.__dict__)
# Lazy loads the entire collection. I'd like only one element.
print(coln.data[1])
# Will output: "True 3". I'd like: "True 1".
print('data' in coln.__dict__, len(coln.__dict__['data']))
```

Class definitions and other backwork:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

# Define classes.
class Collection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'collection'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = relationship('Element')

    def __init__(self, list_):
        self.data = [Element(e) for e in list_]

class Element(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'element'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('collection.id'))
    value = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Element({})'.format(self.value)

# Create schema.
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Create session.
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lazy` parameter with `dynamic` value:

`data = relationship('Element', lazy='dynamic')`

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship

Comment: Although the use case doesn't exactly match what I'd imagined, this is what I was looking for. Instead of `len(coln.__dict__['data']) == 1`, we now have `'data' in coln.__dict__ == False`. Thanks!